# perform operation on select indices of a numpy array based on values in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array **A**. I have an another array which I call **switch**. Array **switch**, is an array of boolean values (and np.nan which correspond to location of np.nan 3 x 3 arrays in **A**) that determines which 3 x 3 array in **A** gets selected for an operation.

Example:

```
switch = np.array([ True, False, False, False, np.nan])

a = np.array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 9.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 3., 15.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 9.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 3., 15.,  0.]],

       [[ 0., 27.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [12., 18.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  6.],
        [12.,  0., 27.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]])
```

The final selected array based on the example above should be:

```
np.array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 9.,  0.,  0.],
            [ 3., 15.,  0.]],

       [[ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],

       [[ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],

       [[ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],

       [[ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        [ np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]]])
```

I can do this by using a **for loop** and iterating through each 3 x 3 array in *A* with the use of **if/else** control statements but I am wondering if there is a way to do this using the built in functionality within **numpy**. **For loops** and **if/else** statements is likely much slower than array manipulation. I've been tinkering but so far have not been able to find an optimal **numpy** solution.

I can restructure array **switch** but array **A** I cannot change the structure/shape.

Comment: Relevant: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Comment: What have you actually tried? Numpy supports direct boolean indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
out = np.where(switch[:,None,None], a, np.nan)
```

Or use masking:

```
out = a.copy()
out[switch!=True] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 9.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 3., 15.,  0.]],

       [[nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]],

       [[nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan]]])
```

Comment: The first method doesn't work but the second method does work. Any thoughts why the first doesn't work? I know the nan is not a proper bool mask but thats how my data arrives.

Comment: It works on my system with numpy 1.19.2. Maybe explicitly use `switch==True` instead of `switch`helps.

Answer (score 1):

This would be much easier if you used a proper boolean mask. Numpy allows for boolean indexing, but placing an `nan` in the array turns it into a `float`.

For this particular example, it doesn't matter which value NaNs take, so you can do

```
switch = switch.astype(bool)
result = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
result[switch] = a[switch]
```